# PyCharm showing wrong parameter info for PyQt methods

Tags: python, parameters, pycharm, pyqt5, qmainwindow

I don't do a lot of work in GUI's, but I've decided to move from occasionally using PyQt4 to PyQt5. My IDE is giving me warnings about some of the `__init__` functions, particularly QWidget and QMainWindow.

If you look at the IntelliSense'd parameters, you'll see that the `parent`parameter has a default and the `flags` does not. The IDE tells me that `flags` is unfilled, but when I don't provide it, nothing happens. Why is this happening?

I'm using Python 3.5.

[image: None]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct signature is this:

```
QMainWindow(parent: QWidget = None,
            flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags())
```

So it looks like the IntelliSense in your IDE either does not know how to parse type-hints properly, or the [PyQt stub files](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5-stubs/) need to be installed. There are only two arguments: `parent` and `flags`, both of which have defaults.

(NB: you should never use `self.__class__` with `super` as it can lead to an infinite recursion under certain circumstances. Always pass in the subclass as the first argument - unless you're using Python 3, in which case you can omit all the arguments).

Answer (score 6):

Installing pyQt5-stubs will fix this error.

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly. Note: for the people that didn't know, we are talking about PyCharm IDE by Jetbrains ;)

Comment: Thanks Rusty!!! Good ol' Rusty at it again!